# mPDF How to Suppress Header/Footer On LAST Page

Tags: mpdf

I need to suppress the header/footer on the last page of my PDF document.  I have tried many things and have been unsuccessful.  I have different headers on my first and subsequent pages which is working fine. So, what I want is to have a certain header on my first, a different header on all subsequent pages except for the last one which gets no header.

As a test, I tried setting the header on the last page to match the header on the first page.  I set my named headers like this:

```
$mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName("firstpageheader",$header1);
$mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName("otherpageheader",$header2);
```

I then add my last page like this:

```
$mpdf->AddPageByArray(array(
    "even-header-name"=>"firstpageheader",
    "odd-header-name"=>"firstpageheader",
    "suppress"=>"on"
));
```

So, my complete section of code looks like this:

```
$mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName("firstpageheader",$header1);
$mpdf->DefHTMLHeaderByName("otherpageheader",$header2);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($s); //Main document
$mpdf->AddPageByArray(array(
    "even-header-name"=>"firstpageheader",
    "odd-header-name"=>"firstpageheader",
    "suppress"=>"on"
));
$mpdf->WriteHTML($tc); //Last page
```

What I wind up with on my last page is the header I defined as "otherpageheader".  I do have this in the style of my main document:

```
@page {  
    header: html_otherpageheader;
    footer: html_otherpagesfooter;
}

@page :first {    
    header: html_firstpageheader;
    footer: html_firstpagefooter;
}
```

I don't know if that's causing the problem nor not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers defined in your HTML will override what you defined when adding a new page.

[Use the `<sethtmlpageheader />` tag](http://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/sethtmlpageheader.html) in your `WriteHTML()` method to turn it off on the last page.

```
<sethtmlpageheader value="-1" show-this-page="1" />
```